# Selecting text within a span within a link within an unordered list... and then replacing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's the HTML I'm focusing on:

```
<nav>
    <ul id='nav'>
        <li><a href="index.php" class='top'><icon><img src="images/home-icon.png"></icon>Home<span> +</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="skillsets.php"><icon><img src="images/skills-icon.png"></icon>Skillsets</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.php"><icon><img src="images/gallery-icon.png"></icon>Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php"><icon><img src="images/about-icon.png"></icon>About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php" style='border-right:1px solid black;'><icon><img src="images/contact-icon.png"></icon>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I want to select the text within the span—preferably only the "+" part of the text within the span (without the space). The way I'm trying to do that right now is with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ul = $('nav > ul'),
        li = ul.children('li'),
        top = li.find('a').hasClass("top"),
        navSpan = $(top).children('span');
    $(navSpan).contents().replaceWith(' -');
});
```

but it isn't selecting the element correctly. With the way I have my javascript set up (there's a lot more of it than this) I need to keep these variables. However, it appears that some of these variables aren't set up correctly, or that my `$(navSpan).contents().replaceWith()` command isn't set up correctly. Do you guys have any ideas on how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: `hasClass` returns a _boolean_ value.

Comment: Shouldn't `$(top).children('span');` be `$("a > .top").children('span');`?

Comment: @undefined So how do I fix that?

Comment: @Michał No because I'm selecting the variable top and not the class. I'm doing that right aren't I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, lets fix your selectors and your double-wrapping:

```
$(function(){
    var ul = $('#nav'),
        li = ul.children('li'),
        top = li.find('a.top'), // you can remove the 'a' qualifier if there is never another item with the top class
        navSpan = top.children('span');
```

Second of all ... you can just replace the contents with this:

```
    navSpan.text(' -');
});
```

Final code:

```
$(function(){
    var ul = $('#nav'),
        li = ul.children('li'),
        top = li.find('a.top'),
        navSpan = top.children('span');

    navSpan.text(' -');
});
```

I cringe a little bit at the volume of unnecessary variables in this example, but you said you need all of them so I won't try to further optimize.

**EDIT**: Couldn't resist optimizing a little. Even if you need to capture all of those variables, you will have a faster querying with an id than you will using `nav > li`. If you have multiple menus that this applies to then disregard, but if not then this would be a little faster.

[Here is a jsFiddle of the working code.](http://jsfiddle.net/E85N5/)

Comment: When I set `var navSpan = top.children('span');` (without the `$(top)`) it breaks my code. Could that be because I'm setting that variable in a jQuery loop?

Comment: "it breaks my code" ... please explain, what errors do you get in the console.

Comment: F12 to bring up developer tools, the errors are automatically logged to it. And I receive no errors, I have included a jsFiddle with the HTML you provided and the jQuery above, works just fine.

Comment: Okay, my console says: "TypeError: top.children is not a function".

Comment: Okay, I fixed the first error by setting `var navSpan = top.find('span');` but now I'm recieving the error: "TypeError: navSpan.text is not a function"

Comment: ull need to provide more code then. as i said, with the HTML you provided, and the jquery i detailed in my answer, i am not receiving an error. you can see for yourself in the jsfiddle i provided in my answer.

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ASAF2/. Don't say I didn't warn you about all the code that there actually is.

Comment: ok first, you need to actually load jQuery (i've updated the jsFiddle to do this => http://jsfiddle.net/ASAF2/1/). second, you only have a link with the class of 'top' when the item is mobile...

Comment: nevermind, i see what the problem is. you are declaring `top` as a variable inside of a function, and then trying to access it in a different function. its a scope issue. create the variable on the top layer, then merely assign it in the function. you'll then be able to access the value of that variable inside a different function. http://jsfiddle.net/ASAF2/2/

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I will mark your answer correct as well as vote it and all you comments up!!!

Comment: Though I was wondering is there a way I could declare my `navSpan` variable above (outside) the `prepareList()` function and have it not be declared until after my `$(li).children('a').each(function(){` loop has finished executing.

Answer (score 2):

1. `hasClass` returns a boolean value. If you want to filter an element, you can use the `filter` method: `li.find('a').filter(".top")`
2. `contents` returns the `childNodes` of an element, you can't call jQuery methods on the returned value.

   ```
   $('nav > ul').find('a.top span').text(' -');
   ```